# Menu Position Problem

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I'm designing a webpage. You can see here : http://www.teknoblogo.com/yeni . There is a nav menu at top (ANASAYFA (home) , KATEGORİLER (categories), YAZAR HAKKINDA (about) ) .

There is a submenu on KATEGORİLER . But as you can see , submenus not bottom of KATEGORİLER link.

Can you help me for solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `position:relative` to the parent `<li>` element and `left:0` to the 
`<ul>` you're showing on hover:

*style.css / line 234:*

```
menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative; // !
}
```

*style.css / line 252:*

```
#top-nav li ul {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    left: 0; // !
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Update 1**
This is how it looks like in FF 3.6:
[image]

**Update 2**

*style.css / line 260:*

```
#top-nav li ul li {
   display: block;
}
```

*style.css / line 252:*

```
#top-nav li ul {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    left: 0;
    top: 23px; /* You should play around with this value as you need it */
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But you can check again ?

Comment: It's a drop-down menu . I'm using this tutorial : http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/ . I notice something . When i add **left:0** via FireBug it's working. But when i add this to **style.css** file, something (maybe javascript) overwrite it and delete.

Comment: But it seems to work for me? Only problem I still see is, that the sub menu items are next to each other and not beneath each other.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot please ?

Comment: I mean on your site, in FF 3.6.13 — But now (you changed something, I presume) the submenu is as well on top of the link. (I've added a screenshot to my answer.)

Comment: @Polarblau , yes that is the problem ! submenu is on the parent link. I can't fix it. Because i can't add **left:0** to my css. When i add left:0 via FireBug it's working. But when i add this to style.css file, something (maybe javascript) overwrite it and delete.

Comment: You had it fixed already once :D — I'll check it again… hold tight.

Comment: What can i say ? Thank you very much :) You're great.